# ClientRequestFilter get PathParameter

Tags: java, jax-rs, quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

I have a JAX-RS rest client with following definition.

```
@PUT
@Path("/payments/{paymentId}/operation")
void call(@PathParam("paymentId") String paymentId, Object request);
```

I would like to intercept this outgoing request and read the `paymentId` value in a `ClientRequestFilter`.

```
@Provider
public class TracingInterceptor implements ClientRequestFilter {

    public static final String PAYMENT_ID = "paymentId";

    @Context
    UriInfo info;

    @Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext) {
        // read paymentId
    }
}
```

I tried with `UriInfo` which works for `ContainerRequestFilter` but the context is not available in a `ClientRequestFilter`.

How can I read a specific path parameter in a `ClientRequestFilter`?

Comment: Could you extract them from?
@Context
private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

Answer (score -1):

Use `ClientRequestContext#getUri`: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientRequestContext.html#getUri.

Comment: This returns a URI and there is no build-in way to extract the correct PathParam param from the URI

Comment: Take a look into `ResteasyUriInfo` to reconstruct the UriInfo. It should at least give you an option to extract the paths segments.